# Select one node from others with same name with Linq to XML and C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am having an issue witch a XML file and c#. The xml file looks like this:

```
<data>
   <weather>
       //some stuff
   </weather>

   <weather>
       //some stuff
   </weather>

   <weather>
       //some stuff
   </weather>

   <weather>
       //some stuff
   </weather>
```

Now my problem:

I only need to navigate to the third node for example. For now I thought I could solve it with this:

```
act_tempereature = wData.Root.Element("weather").Element("maxtempC").Value;
```

But of course, it only selects the first Element in Document directory with that specific name. So what how can I navigate to the 3rd or 2nd weather?

If this question is already asked, I am sorry because I did not find something (maybe I just searched for the wrong keywords :/ )

Hope you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Elements()` with plural `s` to get all elements having particular name :

```
act_tempereatures = wData.Root
                         .Elements("weather")
                         .Elements("maxtempC")
                         .Select(o => o.Value);
```

Then simply use `foreach` loop to get each of the temperature value. Or if you only need one element in particular position, say the 3rd, try using `Skip()` and `Take()` :

```
act_tempereature3 = wData.Root
                         .Elements("weather")
                         .Skip(2)
                         .Take(1)
                         .Elements("maxtempC")
                         .Select(o => o.Value);
```

Comment: In your second codesnippet, wich datatype has "act_tempereature3" to be? a string array, a string list, or can it be a string? I only need to select One element in the specific position.
As I tried it, it throws an error, that act_tempereature3 can not be a string.

Comment: Try to add `FirstOrDefault()` to get only one instance